# Excel: count the number of cells in a column until their sum is greater than a set value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a list of consecutive events in one column and their durations in the adjacent column. I want to count the number of times a particular event occurred in a certain length of time.

For example:
Col Event Duration
1-- Contr 8
2-- Relax 5
3-- Contr 12
4-- Relax 6
5-- Contr 10
6-- Relax 5

In this example I want excel to start from row 6 and go backwards, summing durations until the value is over 30 and return the number of times Contr occured over that time period. Here the answer is 2.

Here's a link to an example spreadsheet with more realistic values: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiOl_zwCwrAmgcgQqCPaOY5WzMZTGQ
(The threshold value would be 900 instead of 30.)

Thanks. Hope I asked the question right.

Comment: What determines the starting row (six in your example)?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Nothing, there's no starting row. I just used that example to make it simple. I would actually like to calculate the value for every row. What I actually want is another column telling me for every row how many times Contr occurred over a given time period prior to the current event. I know it's quite awkward.

Comment: I think you need to add a few expected results to your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to use a helper column to work out the totals *under* the current row. I don't mind if the sum including the current row is 30 or more, as long as the sum *under* it is less than 30.

So in D2:-

```
=SUM(C3:C$100)
```

Then it's just a countifs:-

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B100,"Contr",D2:D100,"<"&30)
```

[image: (will post screen shot later)]

Comment: I think I've almost worked it out doing something like this. I created a column in D called "running totals" which is just the total from above added to the new length. So D2 `=C2`  D3 = `=D2+C3` Then in the next column I added the following: For D3: `=COUNTIFS(C:C, ">"&C3-30,C:C, "<="&C3,A:A, "contr")`

Comment: Here's a link to a spreadsheet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiOl_zwCwrAmgcgS90wVzAdQCLZqhA

Comment: I think I've finally understood the question. I didn't get that you wanted to do it repeatedly hence the comment from @X OR LX is a good one. Your way of doing it seems fine to me.